# How to create an object/array from a key/value string made up with '/'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take the following string:

```
/foo/1/bar/2/cat/bob
```

I need to parse this into an object or array which ends up being:

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
cat = bob
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var sample = "/foo/1/bar/2/cat/bob".substring(1);
var finalObj = {};

var arr = sample.split('/');

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i=i+2){  
  finalObj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
}

console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: Correct for question asked.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const str = '/foo/1/bar/2/cat/bob/test/'

const parts = str.split('/')
  .filter(val => val !== '')

const obj = {}

for (let ii = 0; ii < parts.length; ii+=2) {
  const key = parts[ii]
  const value = parts[ii+1]
  obj[key] = !isNaN(value) ? Number(value) : value
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Very elegant, @synthet1c.

Comment: what happend to the initial `/` in the string ??

Comment: Perfect. I decided to trim the initial / on the string to make this work.

Comment: Is there  a reason for using `ii` as an indexer or is that just something you prefer over the conventional `i`?

Comment: easier to search for with `ctrl + f` you will probably have at least one `i` in your code, but `ii` is pretty much never used.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions is the tool of choice for all kinds of parsing:

```js
str = '/foo/1/bar/2/cat/bob'
obj = {};
str.replace(/(\w+)\/(\w+)/g, (...m) => obj[m[1]] = m[2]);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: That's great but quite unreadable imho and i guess not that optimized. BUT that's just my opinion and you got my vote

Comment: I’d use `([^\/]*)` instead of `(\w+)`. Empty key names and values are allowed and aren’t restricted to alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it,

```
let str = "/foo/1/bar/2/cat/bob",
    arr = str.split("/"),
    obj = {};
arr.shift();
while (arr.length) obj[arr.shift()] = arr.shift();
```